# Regex: Replacing the first character with lower case character

Tags: regex, notepad++

Consider this piece of text(four spaces between words):

```
word    Word  
word    Word  
word    Word
```

I'm using Notepad++.

I search for: `\b    (\w)`
I want to replace with:   `\l$1`

When I click <kbd>Replace</kbd> button, no replacement is done with the text above, but with this text it works fine (four and two spaces between words):

```
word    Word  
word  Word  
word  Word
```

Is this because of Notepad++?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Did you click "Replace All"? If I want more control and want to replace with the "Replace" button, it won't work.

Comment: That is really weird. I think it has something to do with a bug I logged some months ago: [*Word boundary issue with a generic subpattern next to it #1404*](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1404). But here, it is even weirder.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer with a correct solution, 4EACH's contains a serious misleading typo, lacks explanation and focuses on an absolutely unimportant details (at least, for the current scenario).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In nodepad++ you need to use `\1` to get group `#1` and not `$` symbol. 
Try this:

```
(\w\s{4})(\w) -> \1|\2
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've changed the replace statement to (\w\s{4})(\w) -> **\1 \l\2** (l = lowercase L) and now it works like intended. Thanks! Btw: in my case it didn't make a difference how I addressed the groups. **\1 \l\2** and **$1 \l$2** produced same Results.

Comment: @Siggi: It does not matter if you use ``\1``  or `$1` in your case (hence, someone downvoted the answer). It would in some other cases. Actually,  I think a more appropriate solution is to use `(\w)\h{4}(\w)` and replace with `$1 \l$2`. Note that `\s` matches linebreaks and `(\w\s{4})(\w)` may match across lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Your search pattern fits better. Thanks. I hope I will remember it next time.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue lies in the `\b` word boundary pattern implementation in Notepad++. See the [*Word boundary issue with a generic subpattern next to it #1404*](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1404) issue I logged some time ago.

In your specific case, I'd rather match the word char at the end of the previous word with `(\w)`, then match 4 *horizontal* spaces with `\h{4}`, and then again would capture the word char of the following word to be lowercased (with another  `(\w)`).

```
(\w)\h{4}(\w)
```

and replace with

```
$1 \l$2
```

[image]

Comment: Your bug report doesn't go far enough; `\bw` matches each letter in `wwwww`, so beginning-of-word boundaries don't work *at all*.  But this error is truly bizarre.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I wish NPP team looked at least at what I logged. :(